# make div elements inside a container responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so basically i have an outer div that contains 5 inner divs.

```
------------------------------------
| <div title>                       |   

|             <div value><div unit> |

|                      <div subvalue|

|                         <div date>|
```

so this is basically my div. i have set the width and height of the outer div to auto because i thought if i want it to be responsive i should do that. what i need is to give the div height and width but the elements inside to stay responsive( ex: the title should stay on the left, the value should stay in the middle of the entire container even if it gets bigger with the unit, the two remaining should stay bottom right) and i have no idea how to do that i really need help:

css code:

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid #57c0e8;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.title {
    color:grey;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-left:2%;
}

.valueAndUnit {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;  
}

.value{
    margin-top: 3%;
    min-height:25px;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.unit {
    display: inline-block;
}

.subValue {
    text-align: right;
    min-height:25px;
    font-size:1em;
}   

.date {
    min-height:25px;
    color:lightslategrey;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.subValueAndDate {
    margin-right: 6%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {

    .title { 
       font-size: 1.3vw; 
    }
    .value{
        font-size: 3.1vw;
    }

 .unit{
     font-size:2vw;
 }

 .subValue{
     font-size:2.5vw;
 }

 }
```

this is the actual container:

[image: container]

html:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.title}>
            {title}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.valueAndUnit} style={style}>
            <div className={styles.value}>
            {value}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.unit}>
            {unit}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.subValueAndDate}>
            <div className={styles.subValue}>
            {subValue}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.date}>
            {date}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's a nice schematic drawing of your HTML structure, but could you post the actual HTML? A Mockup is fine.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink yes i just did if i set the width and height to fixed to matched the element next to it the data inside will remain in their position( plz ignore the data its just dummy and i will really appreaciate any help)

Comment: What's the update on this? Found what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Bootstrap, you could make use of the Grid style of the framework and make some minor tweaks using the flexbox classes.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="row d-flex">
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
            yes
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            1111 unit
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            1234
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-10 text-right">
            05/14/3030 4:12
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer-div {
    border: solid green 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

**Snippet Example:**

```css
.outer-div {
 border: solid green 1px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 35%;
 margin-left: 30%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="outer-div">
 <div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-6 text-left">
   yes
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-12 text-center">
   1111 unit
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="col-6 text-right">
   1234
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="col-10 text-right">
   05/14/3030 4:12
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/YzwNxVw).